# IMC, 2020, ex. 8 (solution 1)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, contest-math

I have problem to understand the solution 1 of exercise 8: https://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2020/imc2020-day2-solutions.pdf. We have: $(1-e^{-x})^{n-1}\leq e^{-e^{-x}(n-1)}\leq e^{-\frac{M}{n}(n-1)}$ tends to $0$ uniformly in $x$. Therefore
\begin{equation}
\int_0^M \frac{(1-e^{-x})(1-(1-e^{-x})^{n-1})}{x}dx=(1+o(1))\int_0^M \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}dx.
\end{equation}
Can you explain me? I tried to understand, but after two hours I have no idea why it is true.

Comment: you know that $(1-e^{-x})^{n-1}$ has a finite maximum(because it goes to zero when x goes to infinity) so $1+(1-e^{-x})^{n-1}$ has a maximum and $\int fg<max g\int f$.

Comment: Using MVT for integrals, we have $\int_0^M \frac{(1-e^{-x})(1-(1-e^{-x})^{n-1})}{x}dx=(1-(1-e^{-c})^{n-1})\int_0^M \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}dx$ for some $c\in [0, M]$.